# Generate S3 Presigned URL in Cross-Account Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, aws-sts

I have 2 AWS accounts: `prod` and `dev`

In `prod`, I've provided cross-account access to a bucket, `a`, to the `dev` account via ACL set in the S3 console. I've granted all permissions to the `dev` account on this bucket.

At this point I can list, add, remove objects in the `a` bucket under the `dev` account credentials. I figured I should be able to create presigned URL's — however, the credentials I create are always AccessDenied in the page

Is there some permission I’ve not included, or something I’m misunderstanding?

- I assumed that providing READ access to objects in this bucket from `dev` account would allow me to generate presigned URL’s that would allow my frontend app to download the files.
- I assumed that providing WRITE access to objects in this bucket from `dev` account would allow me to generate presigned URL’s that would allow my frontend app to upload the files.

I’ve tried another approach as well, using [this link](https://tomgregory.com/s3-bucket-access-from-the-same-and-another-aws-account/) to create STS credentials in `dev` to assume a role I’ve defined in `prod` that grants Full S3 access to bucket `a`. Similar results — full ability to list, download and add objects in the bucket but my presign URL is still showing a page that says AccessDenied... leading me to believe im just not granting the proper permission, but can't seem to find the docs to tell me which one.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Policy I'm using

```
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::a"
        }
```

Comment: Use IAM policies and S3 bucket policies, not ACLs, for [cross-account access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/).

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the quick response. Updated the question with the policy I'm using. how can I apply this policy to the `dev` account?

Comment: That's a potentially dangerous policy, but the point I'm making is that you should not use ACLs. They are a legacy mechanism that pre-dates the (preferred) identity-based and resource-based policy mechanisms.

Comment: @jarmod understood, looking to tighten it up after the prototype is working. My end goal is to have a single bucket `a`  in `prod` that `dev` account can do anything to.

Comment: I tested cross-account pre-signed URLs via an assumed role and it worked as expected, at least with GET (which is what I tested). I used the basic instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) to set up a bucket policy in the prod account allowing s3:GetObject on the relevant S3 ARN to a role in the dev account, an IAM role in the dev account allowing s3:GetObject to the relevant S3 ARN in the prod account, and an IAM user in the dev account with permission to assume the dev role.

Comment: @jarmod oh! "dev account allowing s3:GetObject to the relevant S3 ARN in the prod account" -- I was using an Administrator user in dev but I will attach a role that has this policy and give that a go later. Thank you!